# Moving Linux partition from C:/

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot, grub

I'm trying to switch to working on linux permanently and keep my windows drive for gaming in my spare time.

I have a 40GB partition on my C:/ drive where I've installed Linux Mint, the rest of the drive is taken up with the windows partition. I've quickly filled up the 40GB and get regular prompts that the file system is running low on storage. I blanked a spare harddrive in my machine and want to transfer the linux partition across to it but I'm not sure what steps to take and I'm a little uneasy about messing up anything to do with the boot record. Does anyone have any guidance they can offer on this or a decent tutorial I could follow.

Comment: simplest would be to do a fresh install onto the new disk and then copy user data over.

Comment: Is the computer UEFI?

Comment: I know the simplest solution would be to do a fresh install, but I've put some effort in the setup already, so ideally I'd like to not have to do that all again.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa- it is UEFI

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating the filesystem always have the risk of loosing data. So you better have a backup. But I think there is a relative easy way to put this extra space to your Linux system.
If I got you right, you have an extra hardrive installed into your PC.
Then you can mount this drive as your `/home` directory, becaus I think that there will be the most of your data.

Short answer of procedure is:

- mounting the new hardrive somewhere
- format the harddrive with linux FS
- move all data from your current `/home/` folder to the new drive
- unmount new drive and mount it as /home/

The long answer in more details need more information about your system.